# Control bandwidth with iptables

Tags: rhel, iptables, qos

How can I control bandwidth in RHEL 5 using `iptables`?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you should go through [your previously asked questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2914#questions) and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if they solved your problem

Answer (score 11):

You can't by iptables alone. You should *mark* packets in the `mangle` table and then apply QoS with the `tc` program.

A simple `tc` script to limit `eth0` to 10Mbit/s:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf rate 10240kbit latency 50ms burst 1540
```

[This article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/advanced_traffic_control), while targeted at ArchLinux users, has a nice explanation on how to use `tc` and `iptables` for marking packets, and the commands and concepts explained are quite "distro agnostic".