# Open a command line window in GNOME Desktop

Tags: command-line, gnome

In GNOME Desktop, when I type `/usr/bin/firefox`, the Firefox browser will open. How can I open a command line window in the same way?

Comment: I know this has come up [before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/control-bandwidth-with-iptables), but you should really go through [your previously asked questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2914#questions) and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if they solved your problem. All you need to do is click the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it

Answer (score 9):

Use GNOME Terminal:

`/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`

Comment: I'd guess you can get away with just typing `gnome-terminal`

Comment: @xenoterracide, I expect so, but I followed the OP's example.  But normally `/usr/bin` would be in the `$PATH`.

Comment: @cjm yeah, not criticizing you, more so mentioning it in case the OP doesn't realize it.

Comment: @user2914 I'm guessing "It works thanks" and the lack of a checkmark is a bad sign for the whole "please accept answers" thing

Comment: it may be helpful to mention other terminal programs as well: xterm, rxvt, eterm, mterm, konsole, etc.